# How configure a ClientConfiguration at proxy params for AmazonS3 and AWSSecretManager

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

how do you do?

I am having trouble trying to get a Secret from AWSSecretManager as I need to instantiate it with AWSSecretManagerClientBuilder with a ClientConfiguration with proxy credentials: username, password, host, port.

```
AWSSecretsManager client;
    if(panelConfigurationProxy.getCheckBoxUseCredentials().isSelected()){
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setProxyUsername(panelConfigurationProxy.getTextFieldProxyUser().getText().toString().trim());
        clientConfiguration.setProxyPassword(panelConfigurationProxy.getTextFieldProxyPassword().getText().toString().trim());
        clientConfiguration.setProxyHost(panelConfigurationProxy.getTextFieldProxyHost().getText().toString().trim());
        clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(Integer.valueOf(panelConfigurationProxy.getTextFieldProxyPort().getText().toString().trim()));
        client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.CA_CENTRAL_1).withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).build();
    } else {
        client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.CA_CENTRAL_1).build();
    }
```

But I am faced with the following exceptions:

```
Exception in Thread "Timer-3" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request http://proxy.sj.my-proxy.brg     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:116)
     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executableHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1066)
     stuff...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://proxy.sj.my-proxy.brg
     stuff...
```

Can someone helpme and say where is my error? what can I change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new configuration object like this,
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;

```
     ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
     configuration.setProxyHost("xxx.com");
     configuration.setProxyPort(80);
```

add then add it into the AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder like below,

```
    // Create a Secrets Manager client
     AWSSecretsManager client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
            .withClientConfiguration(configuration)
            .withRegion(region)
            .build();
```